# encoding utf-8 in Python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, pycharm

I was trying to run a simple code that should count the number of "ü" in a string, but just doing:

```
string1= "pingüino"
print(string1)
```

gives the error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfc'
```

I get that when opening a file you can do:

```
with open("path to file", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file1:
```

forcing the encoding `utf-8` in file1, but what if I just want to save the string in a variable without making use of text files, I'm currently using PyCharm and in File->Settings->File encoding-> I have the global encoding is UTF-8 and the project encoding is windows-1252 (I have tried to change it to UTF-8 but then the ü symbol appears as an unidentified symbol in the code), also the version of Python I'm using is 3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

the way to achieve what I wanted was to add a magical comment in the code, you need to add:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

that will change the encoding of the code afterward the comment, allowing the use of string with special characters.